# Formatting a String : To remove the telephone number

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm having a `String(StringTo)` such as

```
John [0775678899] ,Ann [0776789988] ,Mary [0777789900]
```

But I need to format the string to display it as:

```
John, Ann, Mary
```

I tried using the below method but it didn't give me the expected result:

```
StringTo = StringTo.replace("//[^10] ,/", ", ");
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong or any other way to compute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will format the white-space properly:

```
StringTo = StringTo.replaceAll("\\s*\\[\\d+\\]\\s*(,?)", "$1 ");
```

Input:

```
John [0775678899] ,Ann [0776789988] ,Mary [0777789900]
```

Output:

```
John, Ann, Mary
```

Answer (score 1):

replace regex `\[\d+\]` with empty string

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly - you need to remove all numbers inside `[]`. Try this:

```
StringTo.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\] ","");
```

Comment: This will be a bit too loose, though. `[abc]` will also get replaced by this.

Comment: @nhahtdh there is no restrictions that only digits should be deleted. May be some number may contain letters or spaces, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "John [0775678899] ,Ann [0776789988] ,Mary [0777789900]";
    String[] ss = s.split(",");
    ArrayList<String >name = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i< ss.length; i++){
        String[]splitted = ss[i].split("\\[");
        name.add(splitted[0]);
    }
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Output:

```
[John , Ann , Mary ]
```